# Where is the method "comments" defined in this tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

I notice they use it in section 7.4 three times, once in the comments controller and twice in show.html.erb but where is it defined?

Dont you need a

```
def comments
end
```

somewhere? Can you please explain how they are defining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments is not a method but a model that belongs_to the Post model.

When you call `@post.comments.build`, this is creating comments in relation to a particular instance of the Post model.

Go back and ready 7.2 again regarding associated models.